# Is gradient descent for non-parametric maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, gradient-descent

In my reading of maximum likelihood estimation, they go through samples with KNOWN distributions (e.g. binomial, poisson, etc.). I wonder how can I connect to my knowledge of machine learning.

In machine learning, it's always the log likelihood to be maximized, usually in terms of P(data|theta). However, how we don't even know what's the underlying distribution of data (consider data can be some text or some arbitrary numerics), so can I say optimization algorithms are used to estimate the best parameter when the underlying population parameter is unknown?

But I just know optimization only works when the objective function satisfy some conditions that make it optimizable (i.e. have a global/local mini- or maxi-ma). Then how can we deal with the MLE when there's no suitable objective function and with unknown underlying probability distribution? Or this is not even a problem at all as it fails all the condition for gradient descent?

TIA.

Comment: Could you please give an example? There are plenty of situations where the family of the conditional distribution is known (such as in “classification” problem).

Comment: [Another reference about maximum likelihood estimation vs Gradient descent](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/112428/73930)